# xp_cmdshell to add domain admin

Tags: sql-injection

Did an assessment on SQL injection the other day and the only question I didn't do was to add an domain admin. Got access to xp_cmdshell. Tried `net user username password /ADD /DOMAIN` but permission denied

SQL Server 2008 R2 and Windows Server 2008 R2

Any pointers? I have the domain name and the list of administrators if that helps?

Comment: I'm guessing it wasn't quite as straightforward as the database is rarely running as a user with administrative privileges. You probably needed to do a local privesc first

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought but only have access to SQL injection (xp_cmdshell) to do this

Answer (score 1):

This is by default disabled on those particular versions. For your exploit to work your database user would need access to the xp_configure command to enable the xp_cmdshell after which you can actually add your user.

Comment: The user account being used is sa and xp_cmdshell is enabled. nt authority\network service is the account running...

Comment: @pee2pee To add a domain user you actually already need domain administrator privileges. I *highly* doubt that the SQL Server is running in a context of a domain administrator.

Comment: That's where escalation priv. goes in doesn't it?

Comment: @pee2pee Yes, you need to escalate your privileges from local 'NT Authority\Network Service' account to some domain administrator account.

Comment: I doubt that the 'NT Authority\Network Service' has local administrative privileges either.

Comment: ah yea, I didn't see that one